# Compare two classes and seeing if they are equal considering primitive and its wrapper class

Tags: java, reflection, equals, equality

In the end, I want to have something that does something similar to this, which I will use to search correct constructor for reflection.

```
public static boolean equalWithPrimitive(Class<?> from, Class<?> target){
    if(from == target){
        return true;
    }else if((from == Byte.class || from == byte.class) && (target == Byte.class || target == byte.class)){
        return true;
    }else if((from == Short.class || from == short.class) && (target == Short.class || target == short.class)){
        return true;
    }else if((from == Integer.class || from == int.class) && (target == Integer.class || target == int.class)){
        return true;
    }else if((from == Long.class || from == long.class) && (target == Long.class || target == long.class)){
        return true;
    }else if((from == Float.class || from == float.class) && (target == Float.class || target == float.class)){
        return true;
    }else if((from == Double.class || from == double.class) && (target == Double.class || target == double.class)){
        return true;
    }else if((from == Boolean.class || from == boolean.class) && (target == Boolean.class || target == boolean.class)){
        return true;
    }else if((from == Character.class || from == char.class) && (target == Character.class || target == char.class)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there a shorter and an accurate way to achieve this thought?

Comment: you want to return true when one argument is byte and another Byte?

Comment: You could put the classes in arrays, and loop through them.

Comment: @TheLostMind yes, I want it to be true if two class is byte and Byte or byte and byte or Byte and Byte or Byte and byte

Comment: @Quincunx The point is so that I dont have to define each every single primitive exisiting and its type

Answer (score 2):

The most fool-proof way is to keep a Map of primitive->boxed type and use that for conversion before doing the check:

```
private static final Map<Class, Class> primitiveWrapperMap = new HashMap();
static {
     primitiveWrapperMap.put(Boolean.TYPE, Boolean.class);
     primitiveWrapperMap.put(Byte.TYPE, Byte.class);
     primitiveWrapperMap.put(Character.TYPE, Character.class);
     primitiveWrapperMap.put(Short.TYPE, Short.class);
     primitiveWrapperMap.put(Integer.TYPE, Integer.class);
     primitiveWrapperMap.put(Long.TYPE, Long.class);
     primitiveWrapperMap.put(Double.TYPE, Double.class);
     primitiveWrapperMap.put(Float.TYPE, Float.class);
     primitiveWrapperMap.put(Void.TYPE, Void.TYPE);
}

public static Class primitiveToWrapper(Class cls) {
    Class convertedClass = cls;
    if (cls != null && cls.isPrimitive()) {
        convertedClass = (Class) primitiveWrapperMap.get(cls);
    }
    return convertedClass;
}

public static boolean equalWithPrimitive(Class<?> from, Class<?> target) {
    return primitiveToWrapper(from) == primitiveToWrapper(to);
}
```

This is also how the apache commons [`ClassUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ClassUtils.html#primitiveToWrapper%28java.lang.Class%29) library does it.

Comment: The point is so that I dont have to define each every single primitive existing and its type. I would take look and apache commons though

Comment: I don't think there is no direct way that Java provides for that... I think this is the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be little dirty but -

```
Get the name of the both classes convert those to lower case / upper case and equals them
```

Ex -

`from.getName().toLowerCase().equals(target.getName().toLowerCase())`

```
public static boolean equalWithPrimitive(Class<?> from, Class<?> target){
    if(from == target){
        return true;
    }
    return from.getName().toLowerCase().equals(target.getName().toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: I thought this would work, but there is int & integer with char and Character also

Comment: that might be the case you need to handle it specially